# How to run CPU and GPU function simultaneously using threads?

Tags: multithreading, cuda, gpgpu

I have two functions which I want to run using threads.

1) CPU function, which I can join to thread using:

```
thread t1(vector_add, p->iNum1, p->iNum2, p->iNumAns, p->flag);
t1.join();
```

2) and a GPU kernel

`vectorAdd_gpu <<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >>>(s.a1, s.a2, s.a2, s.flag);`

But my problem is how to call GPU kernal call using threads and join it so that it can run simultaneously with CPU function.

```
vectorAdd_gpu <<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >>>(s.a1, s.a2, s.a2, s.flag);

thread t2(vectorAdd_gpu);
t2.join();
```

Any other way to run a CPU and a GPU function simultanliously using threads?

Comment: write a wrapper function?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: CUDA, i.e. not C.

Comment: I don't know Jack about GPU programming, but if the code running on the GPU and the code running on the CPU do not both run in the same virtual address space, then threading is not a model you can use.

Comment: @Solomon Slow: which is the other way to simultaneously run both CPU and GPU function/kernel ?

Comment: @RAJ, I don't know _anything_ about GPU programming.  I suppose there must be some library you can call on to deliver code and data to the GPU and, to get results back, but I don't even know what its name would be.

Comment: GPU kernel launches are asynchronous anyway. As long as you launch the kernel before calling into the CPU function, and only cudaMemcpy() the results back to the CPU after your CPU function, they will run concurrently anyway without the need to use threads at all.

Answer (score 1):

As talonmies said,

Put its call into a lambda function

```
auto myFunc = [&](){
    cudaStream_t stream2;
    cudaSetDevice(device2); 
    cudaStreamCreate (&stream2);
    vectorAdd_gpu <<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock,0,stream2 >>>(s.a1, s.a2, s.a2, s.flag);
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream2);
    cudaStreamDestroy(stream2);
};
```

then give it to thread.

```
thread t2(myFunc);
t2.join();
```

But instead of this, you can still use same main thread of your application with streams asynchronously on CPU work. I just showed what you wanted to see. Using same thread asynchronously could be more efficient than re-creating streams and re-joining threads, depending on size of work. Maybe re-joining has more overhead than synchronizing and launching kernel here. How many kernel calls do you make per second?

In the following blog from Nvidia, https://devblogs.nvidia.com/how-overlap-data-transfers-cuda-cc/ there is a nice example about single-thread asynchronous CUDA:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; ++i) {
  int offset = i * streamSize;
  cudaMemcpyAsync(&d_a[offset], &a[offset], 
                  streamBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; ++i) {
  int offset = i * streamSize;
  kernel<<<streamSize/blockSize, blockSize, 0, stream[i]>>>(d_a, offset);
}

for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; ++i) {
  int offset = i * streamSize;
  cudaMemcpyAsync(&a[offset], &d_a[offset], 
                  streamBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream[i]);
}
```

this is only one of different ways to do asynchronous stream overlapping.

Comment: how to use main thread of the application with streams asynchronously? Only one GPU kernel call is used.

Comment: I added a sample from nvidia blog where multiple streams are used for data copies and kernel launces, in main thread.

Comment: thank you @huseyin tugrul buyukisik. I will try this method.